# Need help combining the same element of a list of tuples in python

Tags: python, database, list, statistics, tuples

I have a single list from a database that is returning the information of a baseball stat across two days.

So say I have these 3 items in a single list of tuples:

```
("John Doe", 2, 3)
("Sponge Bob", 4, 5)
("John Doe", 1, 5)
```

How can I ONLY combine the two tuples of "John Doe" and add the two following values.

I am expecting to see:

```
("John Doe", 3, 8)
("Sponge Bob", 4, 5)
```

Comment: If you're using SQL, make the database do the grouping: `SELECT name, SUM(x), SUM(y) FROM table GROUP BY name;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another solution involving a temporary dictionary to group tuples with the same name, and numpy to ease the summing:

```
import numpy as np

my_tup=[
    ("John Doe", 2, 3),
    ("Sponge Bob", 4, 5),
    ("John Doe", 1, 5),
    ]

my_dict = {}

for tup in my_tup:
    my_dict.setdefault(tup[0], []).append(np.array(tup[1:]))

grouped_tup = [(name, *sum(tup_list)) for name, tup_list in my_dict.items()]
```

Output:

```
grouped_tup
[
   ('John Doe', 3, 8), 
   ('Sponge Bob', 4, 5)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code :

```
import pandas as pd

score = [("John Doe", 2, 3),("Sponge Bob", 4, 5),("John Doe", 1, 5)]

## Convert to pandas dataframe

col = ["Name","S1","S2"]

data = pd.DataFrame(score,columns=col)

## Filter out the identical name's score using groupby method

filtered_data = data.groupby('Name', as_index=False)[['S1','S2']].sum()

## Convert the filtered data to list of tuples

final_score = [tuple(row) for row in filtered_data.to_records(index=False)]

print(final_score)
```

Steps followed:

A. Import pandas library
B. Convert the list of tuples to pandas dataframe fromat
C. Filter out the dataframe
D. Convert the filtered dataframe to list of tuples

Comment: Code provided will give a Value Error. The statement should be `filtered_data = data.groupby('Name', as_index = False)[['S1', 'S2']].sum()` which uses a List instead of a Tuple for `'S1', 'S2'`

Comment: @user19077881, I have verfied it, it looks fine for me. Can you show what output/error you are getting?

Comment: Error message for `filtered_data =` line  is `ValueError: Cannot subset columns with a tuple with more than one element. Use a list instead.` Pandas 2.1.4.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, though I am not getting any error still, maybe it can be a pandas version issue. I have updated the answer just adding 'Name' not the list.

Comment: There is still an error. It is `[['S1', 'S2']]` which is required. I suggest in any event you update Pandas to the latest version.

Comment: @user19077881 Thanks, actually the method I used before got depreciated in the latest pandas version, I was getting a warning before not error. Anyway, I have tested with the latest version and it's now working smoothly.